# An integral involving poles in arithmetical progression

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Tutor asked everyone a brain teaser in my calculus class. I don't know how to solve but suggested quadrature. Got teased and being asked to do it without using any quadrature. Here is the question:

$$\int {1 \over \sum_{j=0}^N {1\over x-x_j}}\, dx$$

where for some fixed $C$, $x_j-x_{j+1} = C$ for every $j = 0,\dots,N-1$.

I have been trying for the whole day. I got no luck. Please help.

Comment: That "hint" is not a _hint_ it's an essential part of the statement of the problem.

Comment: I copied from my tutor and he said something like this in the class

Comment: What exactly does equally spaced mean? Do you mean $|x_j-x_{j+1}|=|x_i-x_{i+1}|$?

Comment: No. I mean the distance between any $x_j$ and its successive $x_{j+1}$ is always the same. Hope this help.

Comment: That is what Chickenmancer said.

Comment: And is $x_0$ somewhere special?

Comment: One can always change variables to make $x_j=j$.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get properly in the first place.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know. Before I almost fell asleep in the class (pardon me), he said something like $x_0< x_1<.......<x_n$

Comment: Equal spacing means $x_j = x_0 + j\Delta x$. The substitution $x = x_0 + u\Delta x$ will simplify the integrand.

Comment: Taking $x=x_0+u\Delta x$ makes all the $x-x_j$ into $u-j$. You can then try just doing the algebra for some small values of $N$ to see if you find some pattern. For example, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}}=\frac{x^2-x}{2x-1}$, how do you integrate that?

Comment: I don't have the solution but remark that if $P = (x-0)⋯(x-N)$, then the integrand is $P/P'$. What do you call quadrature ?

Comment: @Idéophage Quadrature means numerical integration. (Also, does the form $P/P'$ help you any?)

Comment: @eyeballfrog : Could you write $j\,\Delta x$ and $u\,\Delta x$ rather than $j\Delta x$ and $u\Delta x\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: @Ian : $\quad\uparrow\quad$ and you too. $\qquad$

Comment: @Ian : As applied to present-day mathematics "quadrature" seems to mean numerical integration, but as applied to classical geometry, it means constructing a square with the same area as a specified region, i.e. just about any integration.

Comment: Only one up-vote so far (mine). $\qquad$